# React native automatically sets the wrong paths for gradle

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When i cd to `calculator\node_modules\react-native\template\android` and i try to run the command `./gradlew signingReport`,[i get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsB1A.png). This does happen becouse the path that is automatically set by react native is the wrong one, the right one should be `enter code here`.
The right one should be `C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Cose\Progettini\React\calculator\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android`. So it should go back from template no inside.
Why does this happen?

If i hardcode the "right" path inside `settings.gradle` it works, but i don't think this is the right way, any help?

Comment: Why you go under template\android ?

`…\calculator\android\ .\gradlew signingReport.`.

Comment: Becouse i'm trying to follow  [link](https://rnfirebase.io/) this site. to get firebase connected to my app. And i'm trying to "Generate Android credentials".

Comment: And docs says navigate to yourProject\android && .\gradlew signingReport

Comment: Yes but outside myProject\node_modules\ there are no android folders

Comment: If you are using expo follow this workflow https://rnfirebase.io/#expo